# Can there exists a countable continuum?

Tags: general-topology, field-theory, infinity

In James Munkres's Topology I came across the definition of *linear Continuum* as follows:

Definition: A simply ordered set L having more than one element is called a *linear continuum* if the following hold:

1. L has the least upper bound property.
2. If $x<y$, there exists $z$ such that $x<z<y$.

We can see that standard examples of Linear Continuum are made from subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. My question:

**Can we find a Linear continuum that is not made from $\mathbb{R} ?$**

**Can there be a countable Linear continuum?**

Comment: On your first question, what do you mean by "made from $\mathbb{R}$"? Eg the ordered square has a different topology from the usual Euclidean square. Does that count?

Comment: Does a Souslin continuum count?

Comment: Whatever "made from $\mathbb{R}$" means, the answer is "not every continuum is made from $\mathbb{R}$" in the sense "only from $\mathbb{R}$". Simply consider any well ordered poset $X$ and consider the lexicographical order for $X\times\mathbb{R}$. In other words every sufficiently big set can be turned into a continuum. And so you cannot generate all of them from $\mathbb{R}$ only, no matter how you try. There's just too many of them and there's not enough algorithms.

Comment: @almagest Most examples use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is a continuum, I want to have an example without using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $L=\{a_{i}:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable linear continuum. Let $x_{1},y_{1}\in L$ such that $x_{1}<y_{1}$. For all $n$ we can pick $x_{n}$ such that $x_{n-1}<x_{n}<y_{n-1}$ and $a_{2n}\not\in (x_{n},y_{n-1})$ where 
$$(x_{n},y_{n-1})=\{a\in L:x_{n}<a<y_{n-1}\}.$$
Furthermore we can pick $y_{n}$ such that $x_{n}<y_{n}<y_{n-1}$ and $a_{2n+1}\not\in(x_{n},y_{n})$.

Note that $X=\{x_{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a non-empty set in $L$ with upper bound $y_{1}$. Since $L$ has the least upper bound property there is an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{m}$ is the supremum of $X$. However either $a_{m}<x_{m}$ or $a_{m}>y_{m}>x_{m}$, so either $a_{m}$ is not an upper bound or it is not the least upper bound.

So a linear continuum can not be countable.

I am not sure about your first question, I will think about it and expand this answer when I know how to solve that part.

Comment: Neat. I spent at least 15 mins failing to find a solution to this! Is this a standard proof? I don't remember seeing it before.

Comment: No, I just came up with it. I considered trying to find a order preserving bijection with $\mathbb{Q}$ for a while, but that got nowhere.

Comment: Brilliant! In the spirit of Cantor's original diagonal argument, but significantly trickier to find.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens  I did not completely understand the argument (can you explain how the choosing of $a_{i}$ help us reach the contradiction ?), also I guess there is an error with the suffixes.(If not I would have misunderstood the idea.)

Comment: You might be confused as I have not been as sharp as I could be. If $X$ has a supremum it is some element of $L$ and thus it is $a_{m}$ for some $m$. The sequences $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ are chosen in such a way that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an $n$ such that $a_{k}\not\in (x_{n},y_{n})$. The smallest $n$ satisfying this is $n=\lfloor k/2\rfloor$, but $n=k$ does the job as well.

Answer (score 4):

A linear continuum $L$ is a connected normal $T_1$ space (Munkres shows both in his book) and a connected normal $T_1$ space with at least two points has at least size continuum ($|\mathbb{R}|=\mathfrak{c}$), because we can find a continuous function $f:X \to \Bbb R$ (Urysohn's lemma) that is $0$ in one point and $1$ in the other so $f[L]$ will contain at least $[0,1]$ by connectedness (intermediate value theorem), and hence have size at least continuum.

Many continua exist that are not metrisable (so not embeddable in the reals or such spaces), the long line is one classical example (countably compact but not compact), the lexicographically ordered square (compact but not separable) (both covered in Munkres' book) are very well-known ones. In some models of ZFC we can find Suslin continua too (ccc but not separable); I quite like those myself. 
In ZFC we can find Aronszajn lines (more obscure) etc. So we certainly have a lot more (consistent) examples than just subsets of the reals!